# Delete Cache memory in angularjs

Tags: .net, angularjs, visual-studio, model-view-controller, web-applications

I am new in Angularjs, I made an application where I can fetch data from database or we can even edit it. All works good but when we edit any row firstly it shows it is successful and when we refresh data we sometimes are getting the current data or sometimes we are getting the initial data which was before editing.

I am not sure what is the possible error but I think it is taking cache memory I cleared cache from browser but still the problem retains.

Please suggest me some solution or procedure I can take to resolve this issue.

Any help will be appreciated, will help me lot to learn. Thanks In advance.

Comment: It would be great if you can share some javascript code related to edit functionality.

Comment: function saveCompType() {

            compTypeService.post($scope.complType).then(function (response) {

                if (response.ResponseStatus !== null) {
                    logError('comp type not saved, please try again');
                } else {
                    $scope.$emit('compTypeSaved');
                    cancelAndClose();
                }
            }, function (err) {
                logError('complaint type not saved, please try again');
                console.log(err);
            });}function cancelAndClose() {return $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');}

Comment: Hi Anil this is code which I used to save my record, please look at there is something wrong or I need to do something to rectify my code.